# Information loss in C char array

Tags: c, arrays, memory, char, malloc

I want to iterate through argv and copy the relevant information (starting at index 2) into a 2D char-array with the segment shown below.

```c
typedef struct
{
    char *source;

    char **dict;
    unsigned int size_of_dict;
} t_char_cluster;
```

...

```c
int main(int argc, char** argv)){

    t_char_cluster data;
    data.dict = malloc(argc - 2);
    data.source = argv[1];
    data.size_of_dict = 0;

    for (unsigned i = 2; i < argc; i++) {
        data.dict[i - 2] = malloc(strlen(argv[i]));
        strcpy(data.dict[i - 2], argv[i]);
        data.size_of_dict++;
        printf(" dict[0] at i = %d :  %s \n", i, data.dict[0]);
    }

}
```

This works perfectly until the 4th iteration (i starts at 2). After that, the 1st string (index 0) in the char array is getting corrupted. So the ouput of the printf statement looks as follows:

```
 dict[0] at i = 2 :  foo 
 dict[0] at i = 3 :  foo 
 dict[0] at i = 4 :  foo 
 dict[0] at i = 5 :  foo 
 dict[0] at i = 6 :  P�Te�U
 ...
 dict[1] at i = 15 :  P�Te�U
```

As I found out through debugging,`dict[0]` is getting corrupted after the `malloc()` call in the 4th iteration.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: how do call your program, I mean what arguments do you give to it? And are you aware that you always print the same string (`data.dict[0]`)?

Comment: You are most likely not accounting for the `null` element when doing `malloc`

Comment: How is `data.dict` allocated?

Comment: this is my struct: `typedef struct
{
    char *source;

    char **dict;
    unsigned int size_of_dict;
} t_char_cluster;` And here is the intialisation: `t_char_cluster data;
    data.dict = malloc(argc - 2);
    data.source = argv[1];
    data.size_of_dict = 0;` Yes I am aware, that I am always printing the same, because my problem is, that the information I stored there gets lost.

Comment: Can you edit your post instead, it will be more readable

Comment: `data.dict = malloc(argc - 2)` Is incirrect it should be `data.dict = malloc((argc - 2)*sizeof(char*))`

Comment: @MaximeB.That works! Thank you very much! Could you post your comment as a regular answer so the correct solution will be more visible to others?

Comment: Mapawa, @MaximeB.'s solution is not enough since, for example, you dont allocate enough space for every dict element.`data.dict[i - 2] = malloc(strlen(argv[i])+1);` would be correct. Otherwise you corrupt memory during `strcpy()`

Comment: and `data.source = argv[1];` is also not correct. You use `strcpy` for all other arguments, why not for this one?

Comment: Your `main` is wrong, it should obsiously be `int main(int argc,char *argv[])`

Comment: ... and you probably want `printf(" dict[i-2] at i = %d :  %s \n", i, data.dict[i-2]);` or somethingh similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your allocation `data.dict = malloc(argc - 2)` is incorrect. Since you want to create an array of `(argc-2)` `char*` you should initizalize it with `malloc((argc-2)*sizeof(char*));`.

Additionally, your inner allocation is also incorrect, you should use `data.dict[i - 2] = malloc(strlen(argv[i])+1);` to give one extra element to store the final `\0`.

Next time, you can detect easily these bad access using a tool such as `valgrind`.

Edit: as pointed out by Jabberwocky, your main prototype is also incorrect, you should use `int main(int argc, char** argv)` instead.